# user._id does not match user._id in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

so I have a problem that my user._id matches `"61a242dffecd0e0f7b3e36b8"` but it always picks the `else` statement am I doing something wrong?

```js
const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
if ("61a242dffecd0e0f7b3e36b8" === user._id) {
  res.send("hello");
} else {
  return res.send({ message: "access denied" });
}
```

also, the string matches the user._id and when I `console.log(user._id)` it returns this:

```
new ObjectId("61a242dffecd0e0f7b3e36b8")
```

also, this does match with the user._id but again it does not pick the if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using strict equality `===` and the types are not equal. The returned `user._id` is of type mongoose.Types.ObjectId (or something similar). The mongoose.Types.ObjectId does have a `toString()` method though, so if you console.log it, it appears to be a string. Try this:

```
const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
if ("61a242dffecd0e0f7b3e36b8" === user._id.toString()) {
  res.send("hello");
} else {
  return res.send({ message: "access denied" });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the ID you want to check with `ObjectId` before the check.

Here is a snippet that would work

```
const { ObjectId } = require('mongoose').Types

const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);

if (ObjectId("61a242dffecd0e0f7b3e36b8") === user._id) {
  res.send("hello");
} else {
  return res.send({ message: "access denied" });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
if(user == null) throw new Error("User Not Found");
if (user._id.toString() === "61a242dffecd0e0f7b3e36b8") {
  res.send("hello");
} else {
  return res.send({ message: "access denied" });
}
```

Comment: Explain how/why your solution fix (or address) the problem